# How to iterate through multiple urls (teams) to combine NBA players names and stats into one dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, url, concatenation

I am still learning web scraping and would appreciate any help that I can get. Thanks to help from the community I was able to successfully scrape NBA player data (player name and player stats) and concatenate the data into one dataframe.

Here is the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/lal/season/2020/seasontype/2'
df = pd.read_html(url)
df_concat = pd.concat([df[0], df[1], df[3]], axis=1)
```

I would now like to iterate through multiple urls to get data for different teams and then combine all of the different teams into one dataframe.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

teams = ['chi','den','lac']
for team in teams:
    print(team)
   
    url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/{team}/season/2020/seasontype/2'.format(team=team)
    print(url)
       
    df = pd.read_html(url)
   
    df_concat = pd.concat([df[0], df[1], df[3]], axis=1)
```

I tried changing 'lal' in the url to the variable team. When I ran this script the scrape was really, really slow and only gave me a dataframe for the team 'lac', not 'chi' or 'den. Any advice on the best way to do this? I have never tried scraping multiple urls.

Again, I would the data for each team combined into one large dataframe if possible. Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer. I will learn a lot from this project. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is the same, use `pd.concat` with list of dataframes. For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

teams = ["chi", "den", "lac"]
dfs_to_concat = []
for team in teams:
    print(team)
    url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/{team}/season/2020/seasontype/2".format(
        team=team
    )
    print(url)

    df = pd.read_html(url)
    df_concat = pd.concat([df[0], df[1], df[3]], axis=1)
    dfs_to_concat.append(df_concat)

df_final = pd.concat(dfs_to_concat)
print(df_final)
df_final.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
chi
https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/chi/season/2020/seasontype/2
den
https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/den/season/2020/seasontype/2
lac
https://www.espn.com/nba/team/stats/_/name/lac/season/2020/seasontype/2
                        Name  GP    GS   MIN    PTS    OR    DR   REB   AST   STL  BLK    TO    PF  AST/TO    PER   FGM   FGA   FG%   3PM   3PA    3P%   FTM   FTA    FT%   2PM   2PA    2P%  SC-EFF  SH-EFF
0             Zach LaVine SG  60  60.0  34.8   25.5   0.7   4.1   4.8   4.2   1.5  0.5   3.4   2.2     1.2  19.52   9.0  20.0  45.0   3.1   8.1   38.0   4.5   5.6   80.2   5.9  11.9   49.7   1.276    0.53
1         Lauri Markkanen PF  50  50.0  29.8   14.7   1.2   5.1   6.3   1.5   0.8  0.5   1.6   1.9     0.9  14.32   5.0  11.8  42.5   2.2   6.3   34.4   2.5   3.1   82.4   2.8   5.5   51.8   1.247    0.52
2              Coby White PG  65   1.0  25.8   13.2   0.4   3.1   3.5   2.7   0.8  0.1   1.7   1.8     1.6  11.92   4.8  12.2  39.4   2.0   5.8   35.4   1.6   2.0   79.1   2.8   6.4   43.0   1.085    0.48
3         Otto Porter Jr. SF  14   9.0  23.6   11.9   0.9   2.5   3.4   1.8   1.1  0.4   0.8   2.2     2.3  15.87   4.4  10.0  44.3   1.7   4.4   38.7   1.4   1.9   70.4   2.7   5.6   48.7   1.193    0.53
4       Wendell Carter Jr. C  43  43.0  29.2   11.3   3.2   6.2   9.4   1.2   0.8  0.8   1.7   3.8     0.7  15.51   4.3   8.0  53.4   0.1   0.7   20.7   2.6   3.5   73.7   4.1   7.3   56.4   1.411    0.54
5          Thaddeus Young PF  64  16.0  24.9   10.3   1.5   3.5   4.9   1.8   1.4  0.4   1.6   2.1     1.1  13.36   4.2   9.4  44.8   1.2   3.5   35.6   0.7   1.1   58.3   3.0   5.9   50.1   1.097    0.51
6        Tomas Satoransky SG  65  64.0  28.9    9.9   1.2   2.7   3.9   5.4   1.2  0.1   2.0   2.1     2.7  13.52   3.6   8.5  43.0   1.0   3.1   32.2   1.6   1.9   87.6   2.7   5.4   49.1   1.169    0.49
7       Chandler Hutchison F  28  10.0  18.8    7.8   0.6   3.2   3.9   0.9   1.0  0.3   1.0   1.7     1.0  12.45   2.9   6.3  45.7   0.4   1.4   31.6   1.6   2.8   59.0   2.4   4.9   49.6   1.246    0.49
8               Kris Dunn PG  51  32.0  24.9    7.3   0.5   3.2   3.6   3.4   2.0  0.3   1.3   3.1     2.5  12.15   3.0   6.7  44.4   0.6   2.2   25.9   0.8   1.1   74.1   2.4   4.5   53.5   1.091    0.49
9        Denzel Valentine SG  36   5.0  13.6    6.8   0.3   1.8   2.1   1.2   0.7  0.2   0.7   1.4     1.7  13.09   2.7   6.6  40.9   1.3   3.8   33.6   0.2   0.2   75.0   1.4   2.8   51.0   1.038    0.51
10             Luke Kornet C  36  14.0  15.5    6.0   0.6   1.7   2.3   0.9   0.3  0.7   0.4   1.5     2.3  12.70   2.3   5.2  43.8   0.9   3.0   28.7   0.6   0.8   71.4   1.4   2.2   64.6   1.150    0.52
11          Daniel Gafford C  43   7.0  14.2    5.1   1.2   1.3   2.5   0.5   0.3  1.3   0.7   2.3     0.7  16.21   2.2   3.1  70.1   0.0   0.0    0.0   0.7   1.4   53.3   2.2   3.1   70.1   1.642    0.70
12      Shaquille Harrison G  43  10.0  11.3    4.9   0.5   1.5   2.0   1.1   0.8  0.4   0.4   1.3     2.6  17.81   1.8   3.8  46.7   0.4   1.0   38.1   0.9   1.2   78.0   1.4   2.9   49.6   1.267    0.52
13       Ryan Arcidiacono PG  58   4.0  16.0    4.5   0.3   1.6   1.9   1.7   0.5  0.1   0.6   1.7     2.6   9.04   1.6   3.8  40.9   0.9   2.4   39.1   0.5   0.7   71.1   0.6   1.4   43.9   1.186    0.53
14      Cristiano Felicio PF  22   0.0  17.5    3.9   2.5   2.1   4.6   0.7   0.5  0.1   0.8   1.5     0.9  12.79   1.5   2.5  63.0   0.0   0.1    0.0   0.8   1.0   78.3   1.5   2.4   65.4   1.593    0.63
15            Adam Mokoka SG  11   0.0  10.2    2.9   0.6   0.3   0.9   0.4   0.4  0.0   0.2   1.5     2.0   8.18   1.1   2.5  42.9   0.5   1.4   40.0   0.2   0.4   50.0   0.5   1.2   46.2   1.143    0.54
16              Max Strus SG   2   0.0   3.0    2.5   0.5   0.0   0.5   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.5     0.0  30.82   1.0   1.5  66.7   0.0   0.5    0.0   0.5   0.5  100.0   1.0   1.0  100.0   1.667    0.67
17                     Total  65   NaN   NaN  106.8  10.5  31.4  41.9  23.2  10.0  4.1  14.6  21.8     1.6    NaN  39.6  88.6  44.7  12.2  35.1   34.8  15.5  20.5   75.5  27.4  53.5   51.1   1.205    0.52
0             Nikola Jokic C  73  73.0  32.0   19.9   2.3   7.5   9.7   7.0   1.2  0.6   3.1   3.0     2.3  24.97   7.7  14.7  52.8   1.1   3.5   31.4   3.4   4.1   81.7   6.6  11.2   59.4   1.359    0.56
1            Jamal Murray PG  59  59.0  32.3   18.5   0.8   3.2   4.0   4.8   1.1  0.3   2.2   1.7     2.2  17.78   6.9  15.2  45.6   1.9   5.5   34.6   2.8   3.1   88.1   5.0   9.7   51.9   1.220    0.52
2             Will Barton SF  58  58.0  33.0   15.1   1.3   5.0   6.3   3.7   1.1  0.5   1.5   2.1     2.4  15.70   5.7  12.7  45.0   1.9   5.0   37.5   1.8   2.3   76.7   3.9   7.8   49.8   1.184    0.52
3            Jerami Grant SF  71  24.0  26.6   12.0   0.8   2.7   3.5   1.2   0.7  0.8   0.9   2.2     1.4  14.46   4.3   8.9  47.8   1.4   3.5   38.9   2.1   2.8   75.0   2.9   5.4   53.7   1.342    0.56
4            Paul Millsap PF  51  48.0  24.3   11.6   1.9   3.8   5.7   1.6   0.9  0.6   1.4   2.9     1.2  16.96   4.1   8.6  48.2   1.1   2.4   43.5   2.3   2.8   81.6   3.1   6.2   50.0   1.349    0.54
5             Gary Harris SG  56  55.0  31.8   10.4   0.5   2.4   2.9   2.1   1.4  0.3   1.1   2.1     2.0   9.78   3.9   9.3  42.0   1.3   3.8   33.3   1.3   1.6   81.5   2.6   5.5   47.9   1.119    0.49
6      Michael Porter Jr. SF  55   8.0  16.4    9.3   1.2   3.5   4.7   0.8   0.5  0.5   0.9   1.8     0.9  19.84   3.5   7.0  50.9   1.1   2.7   42.2   1.1   1.3   83.3   2.4   4.3   56.4   1.337    0.59
7            Monte Morris PG  73  12.0  22.4    9.0   0.3   1.5   1.9   3.5   0.8  0.2   0.7   1.0     4.8  14.98   3.6   7.8  45.9   0.9   2.4   37.8   1.0   1.2   84.3   2.7   5.4   49.5   1.166    0.52
8         Malik Beasley SG *  41   0.0  18.2    7.9   0.2   1.7   1.9   1.2   0.8  0.1   0.9   1.2     1.3  10.51   2.9   7.3  38.9   1.4   3.9   36.0   0.8   0.9   86.8   1.4   3.4   42.1   1.080    0.49
9            Mason Plumlee C  61   1.0  17.3    7.2   1.6   3.6   5.2   2.5   0.5  0.6   1.3   2.3     1.9  18.86   2.9   4.7  61.5   0.0   0.1    0.0   1.4   2.5   53.5   2.9   4.6   62.5   1.517    0.61
10              PJ Dozier SG  29   0.0  14.2    5.8   0.3   1.6   1.9   2.2   0.5  0.2   0.9   1.6     2.3  11.66   2.2   5.4  41.4   0.6   1.7   34.7   0.7   1.0   72.4   1.7   3.7   44.4   1.070    0.47
11                 Bol Bol C   7   0.0  12.4    5.7   0.7   2.0   2.7   0.9   0.3  0.9   1.4   1.6     0.6  14.41   2.0   4.0  50.0   0.6   1.3   44.4   1.1   1.4   80.0   1.4   2.7   52.6   1.429    0.57
12           Torrey Craig SF  58  27.0  18.5    5.4   1.1   2.2   3.3   0.8   0.4  0.6   0.4   2.3     1.9  10.79   2.1   4.6  46.1   0.8   2.4   32.6   0.4   0.6   61.1   1.4   2.3   60.3   1.171    0.54
13     Keita Bates-Diop SF *   7   0.0  14.0    5.3   0.6   1.9   2.4   0.0   0.3  0.6   0.4   1.0     0.0  12.13   1.9   4.0  46.4   0.4   1.3   33.3   1.1   1.4   80.0   1.4   2.7   52.6   1.321    0.52
14          Troy Daniels G *   6   0.0  12.7    4.3   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.5   0.5  0.0   0.5   1.2     1.0   5.35   1.7   4.7  35.7   1.0   3.3   30.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   0.7   1.3   50.0   0.929    0.46
15  Juancho Hernangomez PF *  34   0.0  12.4    3.1   0.7   2.1   2.8   0.6   0.1  0.1   0.5   0.9     1.2   6.89   1.1   3.2  34.5   0.4   1.8   25.0   0.5   0.7   64.0   0.7   1.5   46.0   0.973    0.41
16          Jordan McRae G *   4   0.0   8.0    2.3   0.3   1.0   1.3   1.0   0.5  0.3   0.0   0.5     inf  16.74   0.5   1.5  33.3   0.5   1.0   50.0   0.8   1.0   75.0   0.0   0.5    0.0   1.500    0.50
17            Tyler Cook F *   2   0.0   9.5    2.0   1.0   1.0   2.0   0.0   1.0  0.0   1.0   0.5     0.0  11.31   0.5   1.0  50.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   1.0   1.0  100.0   0.5   1.0   50.0   2.000    0.50
18           Noah Vonleh F *   7   0.0   4.3    1.9   0.4   0.7   1.1   0.3   0.0  0.0   0.3   0.6     1.0  17.61   0.7   0.9  83.3   0.1   0.1  100.0   0.3   0.6   50.0   0.6   0.7   80.0   2.167    0.92
19          Vlatko Cancar SF  14   0.0   3.2    1.2   0.4   0.4   0.7   0.2   0.1  0.1   0.2   0.5     1.0  11.45   0.4   1.1  40.0   0.1   0.4   16.7   0.3   0.3  100.0   0.4   0.6   55.6   1.133    0.43
20    Jarred Vanderbilt PF *   9   0.0   4.6    1.1   0.3   0.6   0.9   0.2   0.3  0.1   0.8   0.7     0.3   7.20   0.6   0.8  71.4   0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   0.6   0.8   71.4   1.429    0.71
21                     Total  73   NaN   NaN  111.3  10.8  33.4  44.1  26.7   8.0  4.6  13.1  20.3     2.0    NaN  42.0  88.9  47.3  11.0  30.6   35.9  16.2  20.9   77.7  31.1  58.3   53.3   1.252    0.53
0           Kawhi Leonard SF  57  57.0  32.4   27.1   0.9   6.1   7.1   4.9   1.8  0.6   2.6   2.0     1.9  26.91   9.3  19.9  47.0   2.2   5.7   37.8   6.2   7.1   88.6   7.2  14.2   50.6   1.362    0.52
1             Paul George SG  48  48.0  29.6   21.5   0.5   5.2   5.7   3.9   1.4  0.4   2.6   2.4     1.5  21.14   7.1  16.3  43.9   3.3   7.9   41.2   4.0   4.5   87.6   3.9   8.4   46.4   1.321    0.54
2         Montrezl Harrell C  63   2.0  27.8   18.6   2.6   4.5   7.1   1.7   0.6  1.1   1.7   2.3     1.0  23.26   7.5  12.9  58.0   0.0   0.3    0.0   3.7   5.6   65.8   7.5  12.6   59.3   1.445    0.58
3            Lou Williams SG  65   8.0  28.7   18.2   0.5   2.6   3.1   5.6   0.7  0.2   2.8   1.2     2.0  17.38   6.0  14.4  41.8   1.7   4.8   35.2   4.5   5.2   86.1   4.3   9.6   45.1   1.266    0.48
4     Marcus Morris Sr. SF *  19  19.0  28.9   10.1   0.6   3.5   4.1   1.4   0.7  0.7   1.3   2.7     1.1   8.96   3.9   9.2  42.5   1.4   4.4   31.0   0.9   1.2   81.8   2.5   4.7   53.3   1.103    0.50
5        Reggie Jackson PG *  17   6.0  21.3    9.5   0.4   2.6   3.0   3.2   0.3  0.2   1.6   2.2     1.9  12.66   3.4   7.5  45.3   1.5   3.7   41.3   1.1   1.2   90.5   1.9   3.8   49.2   1.258    0.55
6           Landry Shamet SG  53  30.0  27.4    9.3   0.1   1.8   1.9   1.9   0.4  0.2   0.8   2.7     2.4   8.51   3.0   7.4  40.4   2.1   5.6   37.5   1.2   1.4   85.5   0.9   1.8   49.5   1.258    0.55
7              Ivica Zubac C  72  70.0  18.4    8.3   2.7   4.8   7.5   1.1   0.2  0.9   0.8   2.3     1.3  21.75   3.3   5.3  61.3   0.0   0.0    0.0   1.7   2.3   74.7   3.3   5.3   61.6   1.548    0.61
8        Patrick Beverley PG  51  50.0  26.3    7.9   1.1   4.1   5.2   3.6   1.1  0.5   1.3   3.1     2.8  12.54   2.9   6.7  43.1   1.6   4.0   38.8   0.6   0.9   66.0   1.3   2.6   49.6   1.188    0.55
9          JaMychal Green PF  63   1.0  20.7    6.8   1.2   4.9   6.2   0.8   0.5  0.4   0.9   2.8     0.9  11.11   2.4   5.6  42.9   1.5   3.8   38.7   0.6   0.8   75.0   0.9   1.8   51.8   1.222    0.56
10     Maurice Harkless SF *  50  38.0  22.8    5.5   0.9   3.1   4.0   1.0   1.0  0.6   0.9   2.4     1.0   9.70   2.2   4.3  51.6   0.5   1.5   37.0   0.5   0.8   57.1   1.7   2.9   59.0   1.267    0.58
11      Patrick Patterson PF  59  18.0  13.2    4.9   0.6   2.0   2.6   0.7   0.1  0.1   0.4   0.9     2.0  11.57   1.6   3.9  40.8   1.1   2.9   39.0   0.6   0.7   81.4   0.5   1.0   45.9   1.253    0.55
12       Mfiondu Kabengele F  12   0.0   5.3    3.5   0.1   0.8   0.9   0.2   0.2  0.2   0.2   0.8     1.0  18.28   1.2   2.7  43.8   0.8   1.7   45.0   0.4   0.4  100.0   0.4   1.0   41.7   1.313    0.58
13        Rodney McGruder SG  56   4.0  15.6    3.3   0.5   2.2   2.7   0.6   0.5  0.1   0.4   1.3     1.5   6.75   1.3   3.2  39.8   0.4   1.6   27.0   0.3   0.6   55.9   0.9   1.6   52.2   1.033    0.46
14            Amir Coffey SG  18   1.0   8.8    3.2   0.2   0.7   0.9   0.8   0.3  0.1   0.4   1.1     1.8   8.55   1.3   3.0  42.6   0.3   1.1   31.6   0.3   0.6   54.5   0.9   1.9   48.6   1.074    0.48
15      Jerome Robinson SG *  42   1.0  11.3    2.9   0.1   1.3   1.4   1.1   0.3  0.2   0.6   1.3     1.8   4.86   1.1   3.2  33.8   0.5   1.6   28.4   0.3   0.5   57.9   0.6   1.6   39.1   0.897    0.41
16             Joakim Noah C   5   0.0  10.0    2.8   1.0   2.2   3.2   1.4   0.2  0.2   1.2   1.8     1.2  11.11   0.8   1.6  50.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   1.2   1.6   75.0   0.8   1.6   50.0   1.750    0.50
17           Terance Mann SG  41   6.0   8.8    2.4   0.2   1.1   1.3   1.3   0.3  0.1   0.4   1.1     2.9  10.58   0.9   1.9  46.8   0.2   0.5   35.0   0.4   0.7   66.7   0.7   1.4   50.8   1.253    0.51
18    Derrick Walton Jr. G *  23   1.0   9.7    2.2   0.1   0.6   0.7   1.0   0.2  0.0   0.2   0.8     5.5   8.43   0.7   1.6  47.2   0.4   0.9   42.9   0.3   0.4   77.8   0.3   0.7   53.3   1.389    0.60
19        Johnathan Motley F  13   0.0   3.2    2.2   0.2   0.5   0.8   0.6   0.2  0.0   0.4   0.5     1.6  28.53   0.8   1.2  73.3   0.1   0.1  100.0   0.4   0.5   71.4   0.8   1.1   71.4   1.867    0.77
20                     Total  72   NaN   NaN  116.3  10.7  37.0  47.7  23.7   7.1  4.7  14.0  22.1     1.7    NaN  41.6  89.2  46.6  12.4  33.5   37.1  20.8  26.3   79.1  29.1  55.8   52.2   1.304    0.54
```

and creates `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much sir @Andrej Kesely for taking the time to explain this! I appreciate that a lot. =)  This was very informative and I will learn a lot from your answer.